# How to push the data into a table from monogdb to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb

I have data in the format below : (this is an example similar to the data i have)

playlist:{
playlist_id : '8DaFxSeJ0EM',
channel_id : '8DUFxSeJ0EM',
playlist_name : [name1, name2, name3...name10] }

I tried the below code but Im getting Error : cannot set options after executing query. Can anyone  help me to resolve it. I have added the before snippet where the channel details are pushed to the db.

```
def sql_connect(sqlData) :
   
   mysql_connect = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="",
        database="tb_d",
        port="3306"
    )
   #Create a MySQL cursor

   mycursor = mysql_connect.cursor(buffered=True)

   #Iterate over the channels

   for channel in sqlData:

    # Extract channel information
    channel_id = channel['channel_id']['channel_id']
    channel_name = channel['channel_id']['channel_name']
    channel_views = channel['channel_id']['channel_views']
    channel_description = channel['channel_id']['channel_des']
    channel_status = channel['channel_id']['channel_status']
  
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO channel (channel_id, channel_name, channel_views, channel_description, channel_status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(channel_id, channel_name, channel_views, channel_description, channel_status))
    print("Data saved to CHN TAB")  
    mysql_connect.commit() 
    mycursor.close()

    cursor_playlist = mysql_connect.cursor()

    playlist_data = sqlData['playlist_id']

    # Extract values from the data structure
 
    channel_id = playlist_data['channel_id']
    playlist_id = playlist_data['playlist_id']
    playlist_names = playlist_data['playlist_name']

    # Iterate over the playlist names and insert into the 'playlist' table  
    for playlist_name in playlist_names:

    # Insert playlist data into the 'playlist' table in MySQL
        mycursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO playlist (playlist_id, channel_id, playlist_name) "
            "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
            (playlist_id, channel_id, playlist_name)
          )

    print("Data saved to playlist table")

    mysql_connect.commit()
    mycursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message typically occurs when you try to execute a query with a cursor, where the cursor has previously executed a query and hasn't been reset. In your code, i don't see where you created the **mycursor**. Check the updated code below.

```
import mysql.connector

def sql_connect(sqlData):
    mysql_connect = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="",
        database="sample",
        port="3306"
    )

    # create a cursor 
    mycursor = mysql_connect.cursor() 

    playlist_data = sqlData['playlist_id']

    # Extract values from the data structure
    channel_id = playlist_data['channel_id']
    playlist_id = playlist_data['playlist_id']
    playlist_names = playlist_data['playlist_name']

    # Iterate over the playlist names and insert into the 'playlist' table
    for playlist_name in playlist_names:
        # Insert playlist data into the 'playlist' table in MySQL
        mycursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO playlist (playlist_id, channel_id, playlist_name) "
            "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
            (playlist_id, channel_id, playlist_name)
        )

    print("Data saved to playlist table")

    # Commit the changes after the loop is finished
    mysql_connect.commit()

    # Close the cursor and the database connection
    mycursor.close()
    mysql_connect.close()
```

In the above code, we first create a cursor after connecting to the DB, insert queries within the loop, commit the changes to the DB and close both the cursor and mysql connection. If it helps, pls give a tick

Comment: I added the cursor to the code. please check if it works and accept as answer

Comment: still getting the same error. Error : cannot set options after executing query

Comment: can you help me whats is wrong here., please.@big bob little

Comment: still facing same issues or you've solved it @jazzoria ?

Answer (score 0):

You have already closed "mycursor", and then you are trying to use it again down the execution flow. Replace it with "cursor_playlist". Although I highly recommend to make use of transactions in such case to make sure that either all info is saved or none.